# Is scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.sum(axis=None) overcomplicated?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

`csr_matrix` and `csc_matrix` have all their elements in `.data` field, so isn't it simpler and (MUCH) faster to return its sum when `axis is None`?

My tests showed that for a 99% sparce matrix of 2M elements `csr_matrix.sum()` takes ~1.2 ms while `data.sum()` takes ~14 us, and the results always pass `np.isclose` test.

[Source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/sparse/compressed.py#L581)

Comment: Despite the comment, I think it is delegating the action to `base.spmatrix.sum` which uses a matrix product to sum over rows, followed by a dense sum.  So it's not optimized for the format, but how often does one need to do a whole matrix sum?  Go ahead and sum the `data` if that's important in your application.

Comment: I have to calculate a whole matrix sum a lot - that's why I noticed it's ridiculously slow. There is still no good reason to have an over-engineered method with no speed or error safety profits though

Comment: Create an issue for this enhancement over at scipy's github [issues page](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues).  There might be good reasons for not doing this, but it looks like the performance gain could be worth the little bit of extra code to handle the case `axis=None`.